# Os update error

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, 20.10

I am using ubuntu 20.10when I am trying to update through software center it gives this error

Unable to update "OS Updates":

GDBus.Error.org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedError.Quark._pk_2dengine_2derr or_2dquark.Code1: Prepared update not found: /var/lib/PackageKit/-prepared-update

Please Anyone help me resolve this
Thanks

Comment: vtc b/c This appears to be a bug... [Debian #972506.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=972506) Consider using `sudo apt update ; sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: `pkcon offline-status`  please.

Answer (score 2):

This has been reported as Debian bug #972506 [gnome-software doesn't download available OS updates](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=972506), but there is a workaround for it. The Software app reports a `Prepared update not found: /var/lib/PackageKit/-prepared-update` error when trying to update software. `/var/lib/PackageKit/-prepared-update` file does not normally exist, so you will not get this error if you update software from the terminal.

Comment: How do I "update software from the terminal"?

Comment: @voddan Please run this command to update software from the terminal: `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` This is a great way to update because it gives the user verbose output including error messages if there are any and sometimes also suggested commands to fix the error messages.