# os update and firmware update fails through gnome-software

Tags: gnome-software

Recently my software center (orange thing) stopped working (clicking its icon does nothing).

I'm on ubuntu 20.10.

So I installed gnome-software. Then I opened it and it suggested a couple of updates, but it fails to install them.

How do I debug this error message?

[image]

Comment: Can you add details about Ubuntu version ?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with Debian that is affecting Gnome Software.  There does not seem to be a fix yet or a clear workaround to use Gnome Software.  Rather, it is suggested to use APT, at least for the time being.

[Os update error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288336/os-update-error)